# How to install otp authenticator. on OpenLDAP server?

Tags: openldap, one-time-password, authenticator, slapd

I have setup OpenLDAP server for ldap authentication, have referred following doc for openldap installation :
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-openldap-and-phpldapadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04

```
slapd -V
@(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd  (Ubuntu) (Nov 16 2020 13:41:27) $
    buildd@lgw01-amd64-021:/build/openldap-tdJ5yB/openldap-2.4.42+dfsg/debian/build/servers/slapd
```

As a next step I need to install otp authenticator on this openldap server, please suggest how can i install it ?

Requirement is : This configured openldap + OTP setup will be used as an authentication server for an application and the users added on this openldap server should be asked to enter password + OTP when login to the application.